# How to use polymer core-media-query to change element attribute

Tags: polymer, web-component

```
<core-toolbar class="tall" horizontal start-justified layout>
 <div class="logo"><img src="assets/logo.png"></div>
 <h1 class="bottom">Company name</h1>     
</core-toolbar>
```

In the above code I have `horizontal start-justified layout` which mean the element within `core-toolbar` align to left.

Now I want to change the `start-justified` to `center-justified` when screen size below 700px. How to do that with `core-media-query` ?

Can we just wrap the code to `<core-media-query>` or we have to create a custom element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a auto-binding template on the index file there is no need to do it in a custom-element. also polymer has the ability to check attributes against a boolean by using the `attribute?="{{value}}"` syntax. in the case below `start-justified?="{{!queryMatches}}"` means that if the page is more then 700px in width queryMatches will be false and content will justify left. while `center-justified?="{{queryMatches}}"` means that if the page is smaller then the 700px in width queryMatches will be true and content will be center-justified

it would look something like

```
<template is="auto-binding">
  <core-media-query query="max-width:700px" queryMatches="{{queryMatches}}"></core-media-query>
   <core-toolbar class="tall" horizontal start-justified?="{{!queryMatches}}" center-justified?="{{queryMatches}}" layout>
   <div class="logo"><img src="assets/logo.png"></div>
   <h1 class="bottom">Company name</h1>
  </core-toolbar>
</template>
```

here is it working http://plnkr.co/edit/VYdFOt89E6RH7fTTlZ5m?p=preview

edited for completeness

Comment: Most remarkable trick here is that for boolean attributes one has to use question-mark-notation to bind: `start-justified?="{{value}}`. Would you please add this to your excellent answer.

Comment: thank you so much.  thx to @mudasobwa too.  i just wanted to know the question-mark